# Spark many window function in the same query

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I run this Spark SQL query

```
   select
    c.*,
    count(*)
      OVER (PARTITION BY brand, manufacturer, country
      ORDER BY (eventTime div (1000*3600))
      RANGE BETWEEN 24 PRECEDING and 1 PRECEDING) as countBrandManuCountry24H,
    coalesce(
      sum(isMinor)
      OVER(
        PARTITION BY brand, manufacturer, country
        ORDER BY (eventTime div (1000*3600))
        RANGE BETWEEN 24 PRECEDING and 1 PRECEDING), 0L) as minorCountBrandManuCountry24H,
    count(*)
      OVER (PARTITION BY brand, manufacturer, country
        ORDER BY (eventTime div (1000*3600))
        RANGE BETWEEN 336 PRECEDING and 1 PRECEDING
      ) as countProductCampaignCountry336H,
    coalesce(
      sum(isMinor)
        OVER (PARTITION BY brand, manufacturer, country
        ORDER BY (eventTime div (1000*3600))
        RANGE BETWEEN 336 PRECEDING and 1 PRECEDING), 0L) as minorCountBrandManuCountry336H
  from records c
```

the execution plan is mostly linear DAG and not run in parallel at all, although, it executed on the same partition.

[image: Stage]

Is the anyway to improve the performance of this?

Maybe:

1. Write in DataFrame without windowing
2. Order and cache and query it
3. Run in separated DataFrame and join them